# Getting error while adding column of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes, G1 and G2:

G1:

```
studentId midterm homework final
101       45       69       89  
102       20       22       11
103       11       11       11
```

G2:

```
studentId midterm homework final
101       55       69       89  
102       20       65       11
103       11       11       11
```

Trying to get the output as below:

```
student           Old  New
101     Midterm    45   55
102     Homework   22   65
```

Comment: Am not able to add below code in main question, sorry for that: code i tried:                            code:
 `GBool = (G1!= G2).stack()
  Gdiff = pd.concat([G1.stack()[GBool],G2.stack() 
          [GBool]], axis=1)
  Gdiff.columns=["Old", "New"]
  print(Gdiff)

but am not able to get the student id in output

Comment: @ jezrael, i referred the link you suggested, but not solved my problem

Comment: What is error here?

Comment: Am able to fetch the differences, but i want to print the first column(studentId in this case) it is giving error:      Tried with below code:
new_Gdiff = pd.concat([G1db.iloc[0:,0],diff[],axis=1)   getting error as : 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'. Need help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create index by columns `studentId` for both DataFrames, also is possible add parameter `keys` to `concat` for new columns names:

```
G1 = G1.set_index('studentId')
G2 = G2.set_index('studentId')
GBool = (G1!= G2).stack() 
Gdiff = pd.concat([G1.stack()[GBool],G2.stack() [GBool]], axis=1, keys=('Old','New'))
print(Gdiff) 
                    Old  New
studentId                   
101       midterm    45   55
102       homework   22   65
```

If is necessary convert `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
Gdiff = (pd.concat([G1.stack()[GBool],
                   G2.stack()[GBool]], 
                   axis=1, 
                   keys=('Old','New')).rename_axis(('studentId','type')).reset_index())
print(Gdiff) 
   studentId      type  Old  New
0        101   midterm   45   55
1        102  homework   22   65
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate way using `merge` and [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
m=df1.merge(df2,on='studentId',suffixes=('_old','_new'))
n=(pd.wide_to_long(m,df1.columns[1:],'studentId','type',sep='_',suffix='\w+')
                                                         .unstack().stack(0))
n.query("new!=old")
```

---

```
           type    new old
studentId           
101       midterm   55  45
102       homework  65  22
```